# get images in eclipse, but not in .jar

Tags: java, image, file, javafx, path

Im making an application in eclipse. When i run it in eclipse, it works.
This is the path to the images: C:\Users\example\workspace\example\src\images
This is my code:

```
public String name;  
public Rectangle example;  
public Image exampleImage;  

public Example(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    exampleImage = new Image("./images/example.png");
    example = new Rectangle(exampleImage.getWidth(), exampleImage.getHeight());
    example.setFill(new ImagePattern(exampleImage));    
}
```

I access the image from this code in another file.

```
public Example example;
public void buildExample(){
    example = new Example("example");
    borderPane.getChildren().add(example.getImage());   
}
```

All the .java are in src
All images are in images
In eclipse these directories work:
"./images/example.png"
"file:./src/images/example.png"
When it make a .jar file, the path is
Example.jar\images\
all .class files are in Example.jar
all images are in images
When i run the .jar, I get this error:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image must be non-null
why does it work in eclipse and not in a .jar?

Comment: Can you show the actual code you are trying to load the image with, instead of just the paths?

Comment: Please add the output of `jar tvf Example.jar` to the question.

Comment: what do you mean by output?

Answer (score 1):

To open a file from a jar, use this method:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
```

and give `url.toString()` as constructor argument to the `Image` class

Comment: Better use `url.toExternalForm()` instead of `url.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Eclipse compiles only your code, they don't attach the images to the .jar. If you want this to work with a .jar file then create these directories in the folder where your .jar is located: "src/images/" then place your "example.png" image in that directory. Run your .jar, and it should load in the images.

Comment: When i make the .jar, i look in it with a .zip. The image was there

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Your posted Code won't even compile! Follow this link for a tutorial of how to read an Image: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

This can be caused by two Things:

1. The files are not exported into the jar-file. You can fix this by going to the Project-Properties->Java Build Path->Source and check if you include all files and do not exclude any specific ones.
2. The second possibility is a wrong path. Somehow in eclipse path's are resolved differently. A solution for this is to define the path via a a class.
   Let's say you have the following Folder structure:

   [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwHTj.png)
   Then you can access the Image safely if you use this as Path:

   Prog.class.getResource("img/foo.jpg");

Comment: In Java Build Path is says: Included(All), Excluded(None) under Example/src

Comment: then you should go for the second solution. Place a class in the same Folder or some Folder above and then access it using this class as starting Point as described above

Comment: btw. u generally don't load an Image like that. You can load an Image for example by using javax.imageio.ImageIO
check this link for Details: